# ¿Como buscar una carpeta por el id en google drive con la API?

Tags: php, google-api, google-drive

Estoy usadndo la API de google DRIVE en su version 3:

https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/about-sdk

Junto con el SDK para PHP

https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-php-client

Lo que necesito es buscar una carpeta por su ID y no encuentro la manera, este es mi codigo:

```
require 'vendor/autoload.php';
$client = getClient();
$service = new Google_Service_Drive($client);
$optParams = array(
    'q' => "fileId = '1tV_9YdXbAtAlNjAmJ9ILt2DBICwGWyWa'",
    'orderBy'=>'name',
    'pageSize'=>1000
);
$results = $service->files->listFiles($optParams);

var_dump ($results);
```

He intentado buscar `id`, `Id` y otras variables mas pero no encuentro documentacion ni forma de hacerlo. Espero me puedan ayudar. Gracias!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para obetener una carpeta o archvio usando el id, no es necesario llamar al método **list**, sino el método **get**:

```
require 'vendor/autoload.php';
$folderId = "1uv7vLm20-VJ8ATbBobP645edOD";
$client = getClient();
$service = new Google_Service_Drive($client);
$folder = $service->files->get($folderId);
var_dump($folder);
```

Referencia: https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v2/reference/files/get